# Open popup with multiple section IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am creating an application where there is one Off-Canvas window popup when clicking on the section.
In below code, Off-Canvas get trigged when click on id-> kt_quick_notification_toggle.

In view, there is a repeat of these tables section, and clicking on each section should open the same off-canvas popup with data for that section.

Below code is for a single ID section, but this will open only first section popup as ID is getting repeated.

```
            <div class="row m-0">
                @foreach($tables as $t)
                @if($t->section_id == $s->section_id)
                <div class="col-xl-3 bg-success px-6 py-8 rounded-xl mr-7 mb-7" id="kt_quick_notifications_toggle"> 
                
                <div class="text-inverse-succeess font-weight-bolder font-size-h2 mt-3">{{ $t['table_number']}}</div>
                <a href="#" class="text-inverse-success font-weight-bold font-size-lg mt-1">New Products</a>
                </div>  
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

So now I changed ID by adding table number as below.

```
            <div class="row m-0">
                @foreach($tables as $t)
                @if($t->section_id == $s->section_id)
                <div class="col-xl-3 bg-success px-6 py-8 rounded-xl mr-7 mb-7" id="kt_quick_notifications_toggle{{$t['table_number']}}"> 
                
                <div class="text-inverse-succeess font-weight-bolder font-size-h2 mt-3">{{ $t['table_number']}}</div>
                <a href="#" class="text-inverse-success font-weight-bold font-size-lg mt-1">New Products</a>
                </div>  
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

But now I am not sure how I will trigger this repeating ID in javascript?

Here is js

```
    _offcanvasObject = new KTOffcanvas(_element, {
        overlay: true,
        baseClass: 'offcanvas',
        placement: 'right',
        closeBy: 'kt_quick_notifications_close',
        toggleBy: 'kt_quick_notifications_toggle'
    });
```

Comment: Did you try to add your javascript code in a blade file in a script tag?!

Comment: @AhmedAbdeldaim, yes JS is added, Problem is that sections are multiple and by clicking on any section it should open only 1 off-canvas popup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have more than one item with the same id, which is not permitted. Javascript sees only the first item among your sections. and absolutely you don't need to give each section a different id and repeat your javascript code with each id.

What you need is to pass the class of these sections instead of the id.